# Transfer to Târgu Mureș airport

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, romania, bud

I'm going to fly from Târgu Mureș (TGM - Vidrasău)  to Budapest (BUD). My flight is scheduled at 16:20.

I found out on the net that the last transfer bus to the airport leaves from Târgu Mureș (town centre, approximately 9 miles from the airport) at 10:00 - is it true?

Is there any other way to reach the airport later, apart from taking a taxi?

Comment: Please update your question (Edit it) with the required information - it's currently flagged as unclear, and not everyone wants to wade through the comments to find the answers.

Answer (score 6):

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/T%C3%A2rgu-Mure%C8%99/Tirgu-Mures-Airport-TGM) shows two options, taxi or bus, from the city centre in Târgu Mureș, Romania, to the Tirgu Mures Airport (TGM) at Vidrasău, a distance of some 13.8 km/8.6 miles, which takes less than 25 minutes.

The current [Duda Trans bus schedule](http://www.dudatrans.ro/trasee/tgm_vidrasau.htm) for the route is TG **Mures to Vidrasău:**

Monday - Friday hours 6:30; 7:30; 8:30; 12:10; 2:10 p.m.; 4:00 p.m.; 5:10 p.m. and 7:10 p.m. 
Saturday and Sunday hours 6:30; 8:30; 12:10 and 5:10 p.m.

For convenience, from **Vidrasău to TG Mures:**

Monday - Friday hours 7:00; 8:00; 9:45; 12:45; 2:45 p.m.; 4:30 p.m.; 6:15 p.m. and 7:45 p.m. 
Saturday and Sunday hours 7:00; 9:45; 12:45 and 6:15 p.m.

And, courtesy of @pnuts (whose collaboration is invaluable):

[image]